# Analyzer tokenStream throws StackOverflowError

Tags: java, lucene

I need to find the most frequent terms in a text. Looking around I created my own subclass of `Analyzer` and overrode its `createComponents` method.

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {

    Tokenizer source = new NGramTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_47, reader, 12, 12);
    TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, source);

    try {

        TokenStream tokenStream = tokenStream(fieldName, reader);
        OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute = tokenStream.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
        CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = tokenStream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        tokenStream.reset();
        System.out.println("tokenStream " + tokenStream);
        while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
            //int startOffset = offsetAttribute.startOffset();
            //int endOffset = offsetAttribute.endOffset();
            String term = charTermAttribute.toString();
            System.out.println("term = " + term);
        }                   

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);   
}
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_47, rma);

StringReader sr = new StringReader(descProd1);
IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
LuceneUtil.addDoc(w, descProd1, "193398817");

rma.createComponents("content", sr);
w.close();
rma.close();
```

The `addDoc` method:

```
public static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String title, String isbn) throws IOException {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));

    doc.add(new StringField("isbn", isbn, Field.Store.YES));
    w.addDocument(doc);
}
```

When I run this it blows up with `java.lang.StackOverflowError` on this line:

```
TokenStream tokenStream = tokenStream(fieldName, reader);
```

I'm new to `Lucene` so I'm not sure if I'm on the correct path. Am I?

Answer (score 0):

`tokenStream` calls `createComponents`, and your implementation of `createComponents` calls `tokenStream`!! So you're in an infinite loop!

Why do you read the stream in createComponents? Just do:

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {

    Tokenizer source = new NGramTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_47, reader, 12, 12);
    TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, source);

    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);   
}
```

And then configure your writer configuration to use your Analyzer, everything will be done under the scenes.

Comment: Cool, this eliminates the infinite loop, but how do I now get the most frequent terms out of the TokenStreamComponents?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the OP and being new to `Lucene` I was not on the right track with the code in my question. Continuing to search I pieced together code that works for finding the highest frequency terms. Here it is:

```
// create an analyzer:
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);

// create an index and add the text (strings) you want to analyze:
Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_47, analyzer);
IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);         
addDoc(w, text1, "");
addDoc(w, text2, "");
addDoc(w, text3, "");
w.close();

// a comparator is needed for the HighFreqTerms.getHighFreqTerms method:
Comparator<TermStats> comparator = new Comparator<TermStats>() {                
    @Override
    public int compare(TermStats o1, TermStats o2) {
        if(o1.totalTermFreq > o2.totalTermFreq) {
            return 1;
        } else if(o2.totalTermFreq > o1.totalTermFreq) {
           return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};

// find the highest frequency terms: 
try {
    TermStats ts[] = HighFreqTerms.getHighFreqTerms(reader, 50, fieldName, comparator);                             
    for(int i=0; i<ts.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(ts[i]);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```